# Count a string from 1 instead of 0 in c++

Tags: c++

do you know how can I start to count a string from 1 and not from 0 in c++? for example, xyz are on iterations 0,1,2.. but i need them to be on 1,2,3. I know you can put cout << i+1; but is there any other way to do this with strlen(s+1)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  char s[100];
  cin.getline(s, 99);
  int n = strlen(s);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    cout<<i<<": "<<s[i]<<"\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just add 1 to `i` in the `cout` line.

Comment: In `C` and `C++` we count from 0. In time you will realize it's more natural and easier than counting from 1. If you need to present to the user N+1 instead of N then just add 1 to the output. That is how it is done.

Comment: Why do you need them to be 1,2,3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i+1 is the way to go.  An alternate method is starting your loop with 1 instead and accessing the array at element i-1, but that's a bit silly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  char s[100];
  cin.getline(s, 99);
  int n = strlen(s);
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)   // i = 1 not 0
    cout<<i<<": "<<s[i-1]<<"\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will skip the first letter.

Comment: I know. Isn't that what he wants? I suppose it isn't very clear.

Comment: From the *I know you can put cout << i+1;* part it looks like the op wants `cout<<i<<": "` to print 1 instead of 0 on the first iteration while still accessing `str[0]`.

Comment: Ah. Well i+1 is the way to go. -.-
But I am updating my answer to have an alternate method...

Comment: Hi. Yes, I know that condition skips my first leter. I want only to change the iteratations from 0,1,2 to 1,2,3. xyz need to stay there. :)

Comment: Guys, do you know how to give as argument  s + 1 instead of s?

Comment: @aLx21 • can you switch to Pascal or Lua?

Comment: @aLx21 use `std::cin.getline(s + 1, 99);` (if I understand you right). BUT: I highly recommend using `std::string`. No C++ programmer should use C-Strings (except maybe for `constexpr` and µC programming). Using `std::string` is easier and offers additional useful functions. In your case, there is no reason to use a C-String!

Answer (score 0):

In C++, you shouldn't use C-Strings. Instead, use std::string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string s;
  std::getline(std::cin, s);
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
    std::cout << i + 1 << ": " << s[i] << '\n' ;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the simple answer is really just accept you start from zero - however, for an actually solution you can use [boost-range](/questions/tagged/boost-range) and use an index adaptor with an argument of '1'.

```
std::string str;
std::getline(std::cin, str);
for (const auto & element : str | boost::adaptors::indexed(1)) {
    std::cout << element.index()
              << " : "
              << element.value()
              << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, this solution is far too complex. There is a much simpler solution with less overhead and without the need for linking boost.

Comment: @Unterfliege even so, it is sort of what the index adaptor is there for - and the op specificly asking for something else than just adding +1